# How can I set column values based on the presence of a string in another column in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc I have some questions.

| Example | Car | house | wife | child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car,house | yes | yes | no | no |
| house | no | yes | no | yes |
| Wife,child | no | no | yes | yes |
| Wife,house,car | yes | yes | yes | no |

And so on…

I have example column only.

Else column (car, house, wife, child) is create by me.

1. If example cell contain  car, house then under car and house column **yes** else is no.
2. If example cell contain  only house then under house column **yes** else is no.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @spikey_richie I think the OP is trying to find if the column headers are found on the column 1's rows; but I could be wrong.

Comment: I have frist coloum(this ) from this coloum i want to convert that else colum help

Comment: Nope, I still don't get it. Sorry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case I get your question correctly, this is one possible solution in MS Excel. I hope these formulas should be same in Libre Calc. Give it a try.

[image]

Formula in E4 is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(UPPER(E$3),UPPER($D4),1)),"Yes","No")
```

Select and drag it down and across as required.

I am using `UPPER` function to eliminate case sensitivity in matching, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula for LO Calc.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1;$A2;1));"Yes";"No")
```

The only differences from @patkim's answer are that it uses semicolons instead of commas (which always work and may be required depending on your settings) and [SEARCH](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function) is not case sensitive, making the formula simpler.